# Check if PowerPoint’s CustomLayout has picture set

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to determine if the PowerPoint’s custom layout has user’s picture in the background. I were looking for equivalent of this code:

```
ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1).Background.Fill.HasPicture
```

But apparently there is not anything like HasPicture property for CustomLayouts.Background.Fill. I wonder if anyone know round about for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll tell you whether it's picture-filled or not. I don't think there's a way of learning the original name of the picture, but you can force it with .Fill.UserPicture "full path to picture file"

```
If ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1).Background.Fill.Type = 6 Then
  MsgBox "Layout 1 has a picture fill"
End If
```

Comment: I get it, but I think it should be If ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1).Background.Fill.Type = 6. Or = msoFillPicture.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. My apologies.  I've edited my answer to correct the mistake. I opted to use 6 rather than msoFillPicture because if someone's using the same code from e.g. VB rather than VBA in Office, msoFillPicture wouldn't be defined.